# How to display journal name,credit and debit amount in tree view of pos in odoo?

Tags: odoo

I need to display accounting information on POS orders tree view.
How can I display journal name, credit, and the debit amount in the post order tree view?Given code showing the blank result in the tree view.
Here is tried a code, please help me as I am new in Odoo programming

```py
statement_ids = fields.One2many
(
    'account.bank.statement.line', 
    'pos_statement_id', 
    string='Payments', 
    states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}, 
    readonly=True
)
journal_id = fields.Char
(
    compute='_get_journals', 
            string="journal" ,
            states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]},
            store=True,readonly=True
)

@api.depends('statement_ids')
def _get_journals(self):
    acc_lines = self.env['account.bank.statement.line']
    acc_journals = self.env['account.journal']

    for record in self:
        acc_res = acc_lines.search(['statement_ids'])
        record.journal_id = acc_journals.search(['acc_res.journal_id.id'])
```

Comment: Can you explain bit more and share full code, actually under which model you are adding this code?

Comment: Adding under pos.order model

Answer (score 1):

> **In odoo generally only one accounting entry gets created for each session at the time of closing.**

So if you want to show up the debit and credit amount of those orders of then you have to first change the code and create order wise accounting entries.

So either change the way how it works or should change the requirements to any alternate solution.

Comment: yes, it's not possible to post journal entry order wise.

Comment: Accounting entry is only once created at the time of closing session for POS orders together.